# What is $\lim_{n\to\infty} \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} \binom{n}{2k}\left(4^{-k}\binom{2k}{k}\right)^{\frac{2n}{\log_2{n}}}\,?$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, limits-and-convergence

What is $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}  \binom{n}{2k}\left(4^{-k}\binom{2k}{k}\right)^{\frac{2n}{\log_2{n}}}\,?$$

Comment: Do you mean $\log_2n = (\log n)/(\log 2)$ or $\log_2 n = \log\log n$?

Comment: @GregMartin Very much the former. The constant factor seems to make a difference as to whether it converges or not.

Comment: I observe that the summand seems to peak around $k \sim n/(\log_2 n\cdot \log\log n)$, so working out how big it is there would be useful.

Comment: It can be show that in Maple soft, your limit is unbounded.

Comment: @user48365 That's interesting. Mathematica can't handle it. Can you paste the Maple code you used?  If you change the $2$ in the exponent to $3$ does it then converge?

Comment: Given S. Carnahan's answer, it's clear that this really is a borderline case that's extremely interesting. Kudos for posing an insightful problem!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, we note that Stirling's series yields $4^{-k} \binom{2k}{k} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi k}}e^{-1/8k + O(k^{-3})}$.

Let $c = k/n$.  Then

1. $\log n!$ expands as $n \log n - n + O(\log n)$.
2. $\log (2k)!$ expands as $2cn \log 2cn - 2cn + O(\log n)$.
3. $\log(n-2k)!$ expands as $n(1-2c)(\log n + \log(1-2c)) - n(1-2c) + O(\log n)$.
4. $\log \binom{n}{2k}$ expands as $-2cn\log 2c - n(1-2c) \log (1-2c) + O(\log n)$.  This is $n$ times the following function of $2c$: [image: graph of (1-2c)log(1-2c)+2c log 2c]
5. $\frac{2n \log 2}{\log n} \log\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi k}}e^{-1/8k + O(k^{-3})}\negthinspace\right)$ expands as $\frac{n \log 2}{\log n}(-\log n -\log c -\log \pi) - O(\frac{1}{c\log n})$

We need to consider the asymptotics of the sum of the 4th and 5th terms.  The 5th term is dominated by $-n \log 2$, unless $c\sim 1/n$ (i.e., $k\sim 1$ - a short calculation shows we don't need to worry about this case).  From calculus (or brief examination of Pascal's triangle) the fourth term achieves its maximum value of $n \log 2$ at $c=1/4$.  The sum is then dominated by the term $\frac{n \log 2}{\log n}(-\log c -\log \pi)$.  Since $\pi c = \pi/4 < 1$, we have $(-\log c -\log \pi)>0$, so the sum $\frac{n \log 2}{\log n}(-\log c -\log \pi) + O(\log n)$ increases without bound.

In conclusion, the sum diverges, because the summand for $k = \lfloor \frac{n}{4} \rfloor$ increases without bound as $n$ increases.

Comment: Is the OP right that convergence depends on the constant in the exponent? I can't immediately tell from your answer.

Comment: @Anush Yes.  In the fourth expansion of my list, the optimal coefficient of $n$ is about $0.14676$, and the coefficient of $n$ from the fifth sum is $-\log 2$.  Thus, if you divide the exponent by more than about 4.722967, the limit diverges. [Edit: this is not accurate - see later comments.]

Comment: Shouldn't the function in (4) be $n$ times $-2c\log2c - (1-2c)\log(1-2c)$ rather than $-2c\log2c + (1-2c)\log(1-2c)$?

Comment: @GregMartin You're right, thanks.  I've made quite a mess of this question.

Comment: Can I ask my question again in that case? Is the OP right that convergence depends on the constant in the exponent?

Comment: @Anush Yes.  The OP's exponent is precisely what is needed to cancel the $n \log 2$ from $\log \binom{n}{2k}$ for optimal $k$.  This is why I needed to consider the sub-leading term with the $\pi c$ computation.  If the exponent is smaller, the sums diverge even more wildly, and if the exponent is larger, the sums converge to 1.